# Unable to install Ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm

I tried to install Ruby 1.9.3 using RVM. It seems that it installed without error, but the version of Ruby still remains 1.8.7.

Has anyone else encountered this situation?

```
AlexHo@server:~$ rvm install 1.9.3 
Already installed ruby-1.9.3-p125. 
To reinstall use:

rvm reinstall 1.9.3

AlexHo@server:~$ rvm reinstall 1.9.3 
Removing /Users/AlexHo/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p125... 
Removing /Users/AlexHo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125... 
Removing ruby-1.9.3-p125 aliases... 
Removing ruby-1.9.3-p125 wrappers... 
Removing ruby-1.9.3-p125 environments... 
Removing ruby-1.9.3-p125 binaries... 
Fetching yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/AlexHo/.rvm/archives 
Extracting yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/AlexHo/.rvm/src 
Configuring yaml in /Users/AlexHo/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4. 
Compiling yaml in /Users/AlexHo/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4. 
Installing yaml to /Users/AlexHo/.rvm/usr 
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/AlexHo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #fetching 
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #extracting ruby-1.9.3-p125 to /Users/AlexHo/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-    p125 
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #extracted to /Users/AlexHo/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p125 
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #configuring 
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #compiling 
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #installing 
Removing old Rubygems files... 
Installing rubygems-1.8.17 for ruby-1.9.3-p125 ... 
Installation of rubygems completed successfully. 
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - adjusting #shebangs for (gem irb erb ri rdoc testrb rake). 
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #importing default gemsets (/Users/AlexHo/.rvm/gemsets/) 
Install of ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #complete 
AlexHo@server:~$ ruby -v 
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [universal-darwin11.0]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to specify which version of Ruby you want to use.
Try the following:

```
rvm use 1.9.3 --default
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing this command:

```
$ rvm use 1.9.3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can see which versions of ruby are installed by using:

```
rvm list
```

You will also see which version has been set to default.

The default version can be set with:

```
rvm use 1.9.3 --default
```

If you are running Ruby On Rails you might also check the .rvmrc file in your working directory which can hold a string like:

```
rvm ruby-1.9.3@gemset
```

to define which Ruby version should be used for the current directory.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's `--default` not `default`

Answer (score 0):

Auto selecting rubies is not yet implemented, open a ticket at https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues and I will add it.